# How to map the tables in Hibernate Mapping xml

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table as shown by the Create table query below.

```
CREATE TABLE exp_meta_map (
    meta_map_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    meta_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    exp_cat_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    exp_sub_cat_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(meta_map_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(meta_id) REFERENCES exp_meta(meta_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(exp_cat_id) REFERENCES exp_cat(cat_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(exp_sub_cat_id) REFERENCES exp_sub_cat(sub_cat_id)
)ENGINE = INNODB;
```

I am trying to map it to model class as follows:

```
public class MetaMap implements Serializable {

    private long metaMapId;

    private Category category;

    private SubCategory subCategory;

    private Meta meta;

        // Getter Setters
}
```

I tried to map it using one-to-one mapping but that does not serve the purpose. Is it possible to map the tables to the hibernate mapping file? Or do I need to change the model class? Please suggest.

The following is the hibernate-mapping I have used:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="in.indigenous.exptr.domain.MetaMap" table="exp_meta_map"
        catalog="test">
        <id name="metaMapId" type="long">
        <column name="meta_map_id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="category" class="in.indigenous.exptr.domain.Category"
        cascade="save-update"></one-to-one>
    <one-to-one name="subCategory" class="in.indigenous.exptr.domain.SubCategory"
            cascade="save-update"></one-to-one>
    <one-to-one name="meta" class="in.indigenous.exptr.domain.Meta"
        cascade="save-update"></one-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But when I try adding a row to the database, the following is the hibernate query generated.

```
insert into test.exp_meta_map values ( )
```

which has empty values, nothing in it.

Hibernate configurations are through dependency injection, which is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    ">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema_hsql.sql" />
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>in/indigenous/exptr/domain/Category.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>in/indigenous/exptr/domain/ExpenseLineItem.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>in/indigenous/exptr/domain/SubCategory.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>in/indigenous/exptr/domain/Meta.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>in/indigenous/exptr/domain/MetaMap.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="categoryDao"
        class="in.indigenous.exptr.dao.hibernate.CategoryDaoHibernateImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="subCategoryDao"
        class="in.indigenous.exptr.dao.hibernate.SubCategoryDaoHibernateImpl">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="expenseLineItemDao"
        class="in.indigenous.exptr.dao.hibernate.ExpenseLineItemDaoHibernateImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="expenseDao"
        class="in.indigenous.exptr.dao.hibernate.ExpenseDaoHibernateImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="metaDao"
        class="in.indigenous.exptr.dao.hibernate.MetaDaoHibernateImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="metaMapDao"
        class="in.indigenous.exptr.dao.hibernate.MetaMapDaoHibernateImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Why does the one-to-one mapping not serve the purpose? Is it not persisting correctly? Can you share what you tried?

Comment: It seems you're learning Hibernate. Why do you use XML files to describe your mapping, instead of the standard JPA annotations? You're doing it as we were forced to do it 10 years ago, when annotations didn't exist.

Comment: @JB Nizet, XML mappings are not always bad. One can easily distinguish model from configuration. It is pretty much useful while using multi-module application, and one wants to keep configuration in same place. Abhijiit, can u show us hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: @Miron Balcerzak I am using Spring dependency injection.

Comment: @Abhijiit Sarkhel, alright - so can you show us how you configure hibernate?